# Installing Postgress with zsh (Heroku Tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am following the Getting Started With Ruby via Heroku. I am at the step **Declare app dependencies** (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#declare-app-dependencies) and I am stuck at installing Postgres locally.

I am using zsh as my shell so I think there is a problem `$PATH`. I have downloaded Postgres successfully and dragged it to my Applications folder.

This is where I get stuck on

```
If you are using bash (default shell on OS X), add the following line to ~/.bash_profile:

export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
```

I do this in my `~/.zshrc` by `vi  ~/.zshrc` then typing `/PATH` then adding it in my `#User configuration` section.

However when I go to check if it worked properly with `which psql` command it says it returns `psql not found.`

Comment: okay now it works but i have no idea what i did... i was just fiddling around with it. if someone knows please answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you restarted your zsh terminal.
Because `~/.zshrc` is loaded when zsh terminal start up.

You have two ways, if you want to reflect `~/.zshrc` config.(ex: `adding export PATH=...`)

1. Restart your zsh terminal. close(Ctrl+w) and start terminal app.
2. Use `source` command which is to load config file as below.

   ```
   $ source ~/.zshrc
   ```